# How to change SwiftUI Picker value based on tapped option?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have three options in a Picker that I need to change the selected option when a user presses it. How can I get what option was pressed by the user, and then change the option based on that option? Here's where I'm at so far. I guess I don't understand how to get the index of the tapped location of the picker?

[image]

```
@State var option = 0

Picker("", selection: $option) {
                        Text("1").tag(0)
                        Text("2").tag(1)
                        Text("3").tag(2)
}
.pickerStyle(.segmented)
.onTapGesture {
   print(option)
   if option == 0 {
       print("1")
   } else if option == 1 {
       print("22")
   } else if option == 2 {
       print("3")
   }
}
```

Currently the `print` always prints `1`. Any help in the right direction would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a button group instead and styling it like a picker:

```
ForEach(options, id: \.self) { option in
                        Button(action: {
                            selectedOption = option
                            print("Selected option: \(selectedOption)")
                        }) {
                            Text(option)
                                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                                .padding()
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        }
                        .background(selectedOption == option ? Color.blue : Color.gray)
                        .padding(1)
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are requesting to print when you tap on the `Picker`: what if the user slides it to the side? The `.onTapGesture` will simply not trigger. Not to mention that it messes with the user's experience, as it triggers something at a tap, which is not needed.

You need to track the value of the variable `option`, so you print it right when it changes either by a tap or a slide. See the code below that uses `.onChange(of:)`:

```
            Picker("", selection: $option) {
                Text("1").tag(0)
                Text("2").tag(1)
                Text("3").tag(2)
            }
            .pickerStyle(.segmented)
            
            // This modifier tracks the value of the variable and triggers whenever it changes
            .onChange(of: option) { value in
                print("\nVariable value: \(value)")
                
                switch value {
                    case 0:
                        print("Selection 1")
                    case 1:
                        print("Selection 2")
                    default:
                        print("Selection 3")
                }
            }
```

Comment: This works when I manually slide the picker, but when I tap an option, it doesn't change the value.

Comment: This answer and the other similar one, work well for me on MacOS 13.4, Xcode 14.3, tested on real ios 16 devices (not Previews), and macCatalyst. It could be different on older systems.
 when I slide **or** tap an option, it changes the value.

Answer (score 0):

this is how I will use modifier .`onChange`

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State var option = 0
let tabNames = ["1", "2", "3"]

var body: some View{
        Picker("", selection: $option) {
            ForEach(0..<3) {
                Text(tabNames[$0]).tag($0)
            }
        }
        .pickerStyle(.segmented)
        .onChange(of: option, perform: { value in
            print(value)
          print(tabNames[value])
        })
}
}
```

Comment: Same issue as the other answer: This works when I manually slide the picker, but when I tap an option, it doesn't update or print the value.